# Weird HTML colspan rowspan behavior

Tags: html, css, html-table

Border ALL the things!

I'm writing a HTML table and I'm getting extremely strange behavior. I expected to see all of my cells have a border, but that's not the case in Firefox.

I'm getting this:

[image]

```
<style>
.speciestable{ border:1px solid black;} 
.speciestable td{border:1px solid #555; vertical-align:top; text-align:center; }
</style>

<table class="speciestable">
<tr>
    <td rowspan="3">LEFT</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">Bottom</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What's going on? Am I doing something wrong? Why don't all my cells have borders?

Comment: If you start to lecture me about how tables are stupid and I should use divs, I will smack you. I have about 200 data items. I need a table, and my situation is exactly what tables are for, period.

Comment: Looks fine to me on Firefox 11.0. Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/speizerj/zPpuL/

Comment: I can't reproduce your results. I tried exactly this code in Firefox 11, Safari 5.1.4, Camino 2.1.2, and Chrome 17.0 -- and it worked correctly in every browser. Can you be more specific about which browsers you tested with - and can you retest after a restart, just in case your browser state is munged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOPS. I'm a moron. I had some conflicting syles in my external CSS that were removing the borders.

```
External.css
.tborder tr td:first-child{ border-width:0px; }
```

I realized that the HTML was actually this:

```
<table class="tborder>
<tr><td>
    ...
    <table class="speciestable">
```

Comment: Just a hint, not using words like "stupid" or "moron" will get you further than how you're going now.